# Help me with building a formula

Tags: formula-field

Time to Acknowledge is the field name. The offer letter request & pay information etc are the record types that I use in my cases. I am trying to build a if statement that would work depending on the record type chosen. Help with trying to build this formula field for the Time to Acknowledge field? I started with trying the below formula, but I hit the error.

```
IF(RecordType.DeveloperName = "Offer Letter Request", 
CreatedDate + 2,0)
```

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected DateTime, received Number

What is wrong with my formula?

This the requirement for my formula, if offer letter is chosen it needs Time to acknowledge should display 48 hours, if  Submitting Certificates is chosen 72 hours needs to be chosen.

- Offer Letter Request 48 Hours

  Employee Change Request 48 Hours

  Pay Information 48 Hours Benefits Questions 48 Hours

  Submitting Certificates 72 Hours

  Performance Management 72 Hours

  Leaves of Absence 72 Hours

  Visa/Immigration 72 Hours

  Professional Development 72 Hours

  Internships 72 Hours

  Business Cards 72 Hours

  General Questions 72 Hours

  Employment Verification Requests 48 Hours

  Offboarding Request 48 Hours

  LURN Request 1 Week

Comment: I tried this too, IF(RecordType.DeveloperName = "Offer Letter Request", DATEVALUE(CreatedDate +2))  Still I hit error saying,  Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2

Answer (score 1):

An IF formula has three parameters:

```
IF( CONDITION, VALUE_WHEN_TRUE, VALUE_WHEN_FALSE )
```

Regarding this error:

> Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected DateTime, received Number

The data types of VALUE_WHEN_TRUE and VALUE_WHEN_FALSE must agree with each other. This means you can't return a DATETIME on one side, and a NUMBER on the other. They must both be either DATETIME or NUMBER.

Additionally, according to your comment, this error:

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2

Is telling you that you need three parameters. Unlike some languages, you can't omit the VALUE_WHEN_FALSE.

So, your first version might look like:

```
IF(RecordType.DeveloperName = "Offer Letter Request", CreatedDate + 2, NULL)
```

NULL is a special type that is compatible with all other types, and means literally "no value".

However, it looks like you need something more effective, a CASE function. This allows you to return one value based on a number of different options.

```
CreatedDate + CASE(
  RecordType.DeveloperName,
  'OFFER_LETTER_REQUEST', 2, 
  'EMPLOYEE_CHANGE_REQUEST', 2,
  ...
  'SUBMITTING_CERTIFICATES', 3,
  ...
  'LURN_REQUEST', 7, 
0)
```

*(Where the last 0 represents the "else" option, which must be present, and can't be null, since we're adding to a DATETIME value).*

Comment: This makes more sense, there is no syntax error when I use your above example. But the output is just pulling the Created date and pasting it into the formula, 2 or 3 days to the created date is not getting added. It's simply showing 8/19/2021.

Comment: Perfect, figured out what was wrong, my bad I've been passing the wrong field. Your formula worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for the quick response and explanation!

Comment: Offboarding Request
Time to Complete = Completed by employees last day



`CreatedDate + CASE(
  Type,
  "Offboarding Request", Employees_Last_Day__c - 1,
0)` 
This hits a error?

Comment: @SharuJoseph what's employee last day? If it's a number, it'd be okay. Otherwise, you might need an if statement here.

Comment: Employee last date is a date field.

Comment: @SharuJoseph you can't combine datetime and number. What date are you trying to calculate?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the time to complete field which is a date/time field.

Comment: For the Offboarding Request request type, the time to complete is calculated based on the last date of the employee?